# SiteCatalyst (Omniture) Order of Operations: Tagging vs. Configuration?

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

What is best to do first: configure Sitecatalyst (Omniture) within the platform (so naming the reports/variables), or deploying the tags?

Comment: you need to create a report suite in order to know the report suite id to specify where the data should go to in your code (`s_account`) so that must come first (well, it's not a random id so i guess you can decide ahead of time and hope you don't typo!). Also, SC will not record data for some of them if they aren't enabled/configured (e.g. `eVars`) since certain settings dictate how they are stored in their system. But ideally you shouldn't be QAing or looking at reports until both are done anyways, so that 2nd point is minor.  Beyond that, it doesn't really matter which comes first.

Answer (score 2):

You can get some standard reports by just tagging for the standard variables (pagename, products and events like scAdd, purchase etc) but you have to define the metrics your company specifically needs at some point to get the most out of Analytics to report against KPIs etc.

It is important to understand (on paper etc) the business KPIs and reports your business needs to see, then define/configure the variables (eVars/events/Props) so that they support the KPIs/Reports, then do tagging to support these variables, then when you have data in the system design the reports/dashboards in Analytics (SiteCatalyst). Then iterate over this lots of times.

Comment: I agree: if you want to have a real "first step" it'd be "KPI Identification"

Answer (score 0):

I would answer "at the same time". In case of standard implementation, configuration would happen a bit earlier, in case of usage of Context Data Variables it can go the opposite way, but as Crayon mentioned, the reports doesn't make sense until you do both of the activities.

And after all I would highly recommend to the the analysis and documentation before both of these steps.